# Mapping over an array of Tasks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, fantasyland, folktale

So I've started looking at Ramda / Folktale. I'm having an issue trying to map over an array of Tasks that comes from a directory. I'm trying to parse file contents.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var R = require('ramda');
var Task = require('data.task');

var compose = R.compose;
var map = R.map;
var chain = R.chain;


function parseFile(data) {
      console.log("Name: " + data.match(/\$name:(.*)/)[1]);
      console.log("Description: " + data.match(/\$description:(.*)/)[1]);
      console.log("Example path: " + data.match(/\$example:(.*)/)[1]);
}

// String => Task [String]
function readDirectories(path) {
    return new Task(function(reject, resolve) {
        fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(files);
        })
    })
}

// String => Task String
function readFile(file) {
    return new Task(function(reject, resolve) {
        fs.readFile('./src/less/' + file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
        })
    })
}

var app = compose(chain(readFile), readDirectories);

app('./src/less').fork(
    function(error) { throw error },
    function(data)  { util.log(data) }
);
```

I'm reading the files in a directory and returning a Task. When this resolves it should go into the readFile function (which returns a new task). Once it reads the file I want it to just parse some bits out of there.

With the following:

```
var app = compose(chain(readFile), readDirectories);
```

It gets into the readFile function but 'file' is an array of files so it errors.

With:

```
var app = compose(chain(map(readFile)), readDirectories);
```

We never get into fs.readfile(), but 'file' is the actual file name.

I'm pretty stumped on this and the documentation is baffling. Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

const Task = require('data.task');
const R = require('ramda');


//    parseFile :: String -> { name :: String
//                           , description :: String
//                           , example :: String }
const parseFile = data => ({
  name:         R.nth(1, R.match(/[$]name:(.*)/, data)),
  description:  R.nth(1, R.match(/[$]description:(.*)/, data)),
  example:      R.nth(1, R.match(/[$]example:(.*)/, data)),
});

//    readDirectories :: String -> Task (Array String)
const readDirectories = path =>
  new Task((reject, resolve) => {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, filenames) => {
      err == null ? resolve(filenames) : reject(err);
    })
  });

//    readFile :: String -> Task String
const readFile = filename =>
  new Task(function(reject, resolve) {
    fs.readFile('./src/less/' + filename, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      err == null ? resolve(data) : reject(err);
    })
  });

//    dirs :: Task (Array String)
const dirs = readDirectories('./src/less');

//    files :: Task (Array (Task String))
const files = R.map(R.map(readFile), dirs);

//    sequenced :: Task (Task (Array String))
const sequenced = R.map(R.sequence(Task.of), files);

//    unnested :: Task (Array String)
const unnested = R.unnest(sequenced);

//    parsed :: Task (Array { name :: String
//                          , description :: String
//                          , example :: String })
const parsed = R.map(R.map(parseFile), unnested);

parsed.fork(err => {
              process.stderr.write(err.message);
              process.exit(1);
            },
            data => {
              process.stdout.write(R.toString(data));
              process.exit(0);
            });
```

I wrote each of the transformations on a separate line so I could include type signatures which make the nested maps easier to understand. These could of course be combined into a pipeline via [`R.pipe`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe).

The most interesting steps are using [`R.sequence`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#sequence) to transform `Array (Task String)` into `Task (Array String)`, and using [`R.unnest`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#unnest) to transform `Task (Task (Array String))` into `Task (Array String)`.

I suggest having a look at [plaid/async-problem](https://github.com/plaid/async-problem) if you have not already done so.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually really interesting. It's such a shift in thinking I've been strugging with it. Back to the Dr Boolean book.

Comment: I can't find commute in the ramda documentation.  What am I missing?

Comment: also (since I can't find the documentation) how is commute different than "control.monads" sequence function?

Comment: `R.commute` was renamed [`R.sequence`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#sequence) in [ramda/ramda#1467](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1467). I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As David has suggested, `commute` is useful for converting a list of some applicatives (such as `Task`) into a single applicative containing the list of values.

> `var app = compose(chain(map(readFile)), readDirectories);`
>
> We never get into fs.readfile(), but 'file' is the actual file name.

The closely related [`commuteMap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#commuteMap) can help here too as it will take care of the separate `map` step, meaning the code above should also be able to be represented as:

```
var app = compose(chain(commuteMap(readFile, Task.of)), readDirectories);
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem of reading all the files in a directory and started with ramda's pipeP:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const promisify = require("es6-promisify");
const _ = require('ramda');

const path = './src/less/';
const log  = function(x){ console.dir(x); return x };
const map  = _.map;
const take = _.take;

const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
const readFile = _.curry(fs.readFile);
const readTextFile = readFile(_.__, 'utf8');
const readTextFileP = promisify(readTextFile);

var app = _.pipeP(
  readdir,
  take(2),  // for debugging, so don’t waste time reading all the files
  map(_.concat(path)),
  map(readTextFileP),
  promiseAll,
  map(take(50)),
  log
  );

function promiseAll(arr) {
  return Promise.all(arr)
}

app(path);
```

Promise.all seems to be required when reading the files as pipeP expects a value or a promise, but is receiving an array of promises to read the files. What puzzles me is why I had to make a function return the `Promise.all` instead of inlining it.

Your usage of task/fork is intriguing because error handling is built in. Would like pipeP to have a catch block, because without it need to inject maybe, which is hard for a beginner like me to get that right.